# How can you change the colour of text in pygame on keypress?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, colors, pygame

I'm a complete amateur when it comes to pygame, and I need to make a program that will change the colour of the text when the text travels in a different direction. Meaning that on each keypress, (up, down, left, right) the colour will be different. So far I've been able to get the text moving in each direction, however I don't understand how to get the colour to change! Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

```
import pygame
import sys
pygame.init()
screenSize = (800,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenSize),0)
go = True

#Define Colours
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
FUCHSIA = (255, 0, 255)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
LIME = (0, 128, 0)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
NAVYBLUE = (0, 0, 128)
OLIVE = (128, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
TEAL = (0,128,128)

x = 25
y = 25
dx = 0
dy = 0
colour = RED

font = pygame.font.SysFont ("Arial", 72)
text = font.render ("Hello!", True, (colour))

while go:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            go = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                dx = -5
                colour = GRAY

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = 5
                colour = MAROON

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                dy = -5
                colour = BLACK

            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dy = 5
                colour = NAVYBLUE

            elif event.key == pygame.K_c:
                x = (400 - (text.get_width()) // 2)
                y = (300 - (text.get_height()) // 2)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                dx = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                dy = 0

    x = x + dx
    y = y + dy

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    screen.blit (text, (x,y))


    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to render the text again. So after all your if statements where you change `colour`. After all those you need to call `font.render()` again.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        colour = GRAY
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        colour = MAROON
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        colour = BLACK
    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        colour = NAVYBLUE

    text = font.render("Hello!", True, (colour))
```

*I've removed the unrelated stuff. Just to show the context of where to add it.*